# On form submitting : Parameter count does not match Parameter Value count?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to register on an asp site but I am getting following error as :

```
Registration Failed ! Parameter count does not match Parameter Value count
```

The Link Of Registration Page : https://myunitedforms.com/Registration.aspx

The Error Screen : 
[image]

You can look for yourself while to visit the page and apply for a signup at the end when submitting the form you will get the same error..!

I have access to hosting and here are the two source files as :

File Name : Registration.aspx

```
<%--<%@ Register Assembly="MSCaptcha" Namespace="MSCaptcha" TagPrefix="cc1" %>--%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="recaptcha" Namespace="Recaptcha" Assembly="Recaptcha" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _SuccessMess;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAgentWorkPhone').setMask({ mask: '(999) 999-9999', fixedChars: '[(),.:/ -]' }).watermark("(###)###-####");
            $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAgentCellphone').setMask({ mask: '(999) 999-9999', fixedChars: '[(),.:/ -]' }).watermark("(###)###-####");
            $("form").validate();
            if (_SuccessMess == 1) $(".message-success").show("slow");
            if (_SuccessMess == 0) $(".message-error").show("slow");
            $('#recaptcha_response_field').addClass('required');
            $('#recaptcha_response_field').val('required');
        });

        function validateCAPTCHA() {
            var response = $('#recaptcha_response_field').val();
            if (response == null || response == '') {
                $('#recaptcha_response_field').addClass('required error');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <div class="box">
        <!-- box / title -->
        <div class="title">
            <h5>
                Registration</h5>
        </div>
        <!-- end box / title -->
        <div class="form">
            <div class="fields">
                <div class="field field-first">
                    <div class="label">
                        User Name
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input runat="server" name="txtUserName" class="required" id="txtUserName" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field field-first">
                    <div class="label">
                        Password
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input runat="server" name="txtPassword" class="required" id="txtPassword" type="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field field-first">
                    <div class="label">
                        Agent
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input runat="server" size="75" name="txtAgent" class="required" id="txtAgent" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field field-first">
                    <div class="label">
                        Brokerage Firm
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input runat="server" size="75" name="txtBrokerageFirm" class="required" id="txtBrokerageFirm"
                            type="text"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="field field-first">
                    <div class="label">
                        Address
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <textarea runat="server" cols="75" rows="3" name="txtAgentWorkAddress" id="txtAgentWorkAddress" /></div>
                </div>
                <div class="field field-first">
                    <div class="label">
                        City
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input runat="server" name="txtAgentCity" id="txtAgentCity" type="text"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="field field-first">
                    <div class="label">
                        State
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input runat="server" name="txtAgentSt" id="txtAgentSt" type="text"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="field field-first">
                    <div class="label">
                        Zip</div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input runat="server" name="txtAgentZip" id="txtAgentZip" type="text"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="field field-first">
                    <div class="label">
                        Phone
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input runat="server" name="txtAgentWorkPhone" id="txtAgentWorkPhone" type="text"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="field field-first">
                    <div class="label">
                        Cell
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input runat="server" name="txtAgentCellphone" id="txtAgentCellphone" type="text"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="field field-first">
                    <div class="label">
                        Email
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input id="txtAgentEmail" runat="server" size="75" class="required email" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field field-first">
                    <div class="label">
                        Docusign Email
                    </div>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input id="txtDocusignEmail" runat="server" size="75" class="email" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box_captcha" style="padding: 0 0 0 20px; margin: -10px 0 0 0;">
        <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="recaptcha" Theme="clean" runat="server" PublicKey="6Ld8vvMSAAAAALMXpOhqQIPHNKL1o_aLjDTzx7sY"
            PrivateKey="6Ld8vvMSAAAAAAFAIKpMMQfTDGb4RsIOi-01bfUj" />
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="margin: 0px 0 0 0;">
        <div class="form">
            <div class="fields">
                <div class="message message-success" id="message-success" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img height="32" alt="Success" src="resources/images/icons/success.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <h6>Registration Successful !</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="message message-error" id="message-error" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img height="32" alt="Error" src="resources/images/icons/error.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <h6>Registration Failed !</h6>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field field-first">
                    <div class="label">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" OnClientClick="return validateCAPTCHA();" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

And

File Name : Registration.aspx.cs

```
using GlobalLayer;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Profile;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Registration : Page, IRequiresSessionState
{


    protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            recaptcha.Validate();
            if (!recaptcha.IsValid)
            {
                throw new Exception(recaptcha.ErrorMessage);
            }
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                lblErrorMessage.Text = "";
                DataSet dataBySP = new DataSet();
                object[] parameters = new object[] { this.txtUserName.Value, this.txtPassword.Value, this.txtAgent.Value, this.txtBrokerageFirm.Value, this.txtAgentWorkAddress.Value, this.txtAgentCity.Value, this.txtAgentSt.Value, this.txtAgentZip.Value, this.txtAgentWorkPhone.Value, this.txtAgentCellphone.Value, this.txtAgentEmail.Value, txtDocusignEmail.Value, 1, false, 0 };
                dataBySP = DAL.GetDataBySP("sp_RegisterUser", parameters);
                if ((dataBySP.Tables.Count > 0) && (dataBySP.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0))
                {
                    UserData.UserID = dataBySP.Tables[0].Rows[0]["pk_UserId"].ToString();
                    UserData.UserName = dataBySP.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString();

                    string validationKey = CustomEncryption.Encrypt(UserData.UserID + UserData.UserName + DateTime.Now.ToString());

                    object[] invParameters = new object[] { UserData.UserID, validationKey };
                    DAL.ExecuteSP("sp_SetUserInvitationKey", invParameters);

                    string emailsent = EmailUtility.NewUserEmail(UserData.UserID, this.txtAgentEmail.Value, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(validationKey), UserData.UserName);
                    if (emailsent != "success")
                    {
                        throw new Exception(emailsent);
                    }

                    base.Response.Redirect("AccountCreated.aspx");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid page inputs.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            this.lblErrorMessage.Text = exception.Message;
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "lblMessage123", "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">_SuccessMess=0;</script>");
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            (base.Master.FindControl("lblLoginUserName") as LinkButton).Text = "Guest";
            this.txtBrokerageFirm.Value = "United Real Estate Solutions, Inc";
            this.txtAgentWorkAddress.Value = "302 Jones St, Suite 100";
            this.txtAgentCity.Value = "Sioux City";
            this.txtAgentSt.Value = "IA";
            this.txtAgentZip.Value = "51101";
            this.txtAgentWorkPhone.Value = "(712) 226-6000";
        }
    }

    //private void SendMail()
    //{
    //    string str2 = File.ReadAllText(base.Server.MapPath("~/Template/RegistrationnEmail.htm")).Replace("@@UserName", this.txtUserName.Value.Trim()).Replace("@@Password", this.txtPassword.Value.Trim()).Replace("@@Agent", this.txtAgent.Value.Trim()).Replace("@@BrokerageFirm", this.txtBrokerageFirm.Value.Trim()).Replace("@@Address", this.txtAgentWorkAddress.Value.Trim()).Replace("@@City", this.txtAgentCity.Value.Trim()).Replace("@@State", this.txtAgentSt.Value.Trim()).Replace("@@Zip", this.txtAgentZip.Value.Trim()).Replace("@@Phone", this.txtAgentWorkPhone.Value.Trim()).Replace("@@Cell", this.txtAgentCellphone.Value.Trim());
    //    MailMessage message = new MailMessage {
    //        From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromAddress"].ToString()),
    //        Subject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Subject"].ToString(),
    //        IsBodyHtml = true,
    //        Body = str2
    //    };
    //    MailAddress item = new MailAddress(this.txtAgentEmail.Value.Trim());
    //    message.To.Add(item);
    //    new SmtpClient().Send(message);
    //}


}
```

As I am not familiar with asp.net as I am familiar with PHP so I need your help to let me know what is wrong with it and let me know how to fix it?

Here is `sp_SetUserInvitationKey` :

```
USE [CommercialSiteDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_SetUserInvitationKey]    Script Date: 2/12/2016 11:38:40 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SetUserInvitationKey]

    @UserId int,  
    @InvitationKey NVARCHAR(255)

AS

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.tbl_UserMaster_Mst set InvitationKey=@InvitationKey, InvitedOn=GETDATE(), IsLocked = 1
    Where pk_UserId = @UserID

END
```

The Screenshot as :
[image]

[image]

Here is `sp_RegisterUser` :

```
USE [CommercialSiteDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_RegisterUser]    Script Date: 2/13/2016 1:18:24 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_RegisterUser]
@UserName VARCHAR(50),  
@Password VARCHAR(50), 
@Agent VARCHAR(50), 
@BrokerageFirm VARCHAR(100), 
@Address VARCHAR(1000), 
@City VARCHAR(50), 
@State VARCHAR(50), 
@Zip VARCHAR(10), 
@Phone VARCHAR(15), 
@Cell VARCHAR(15), 
@Email VARCHAR(255), 
--@DocusignEmail varchar(255),
@Status TINYINT,
@UserID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

if(@UserID=0)
begin
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT pk_UserId FROM  dbo.tbl_UserMaster_Mst  WHERE UserName=@UserName )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_UserMaster_Mst (UserName, Password, Agent, BrokerageFirm, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone, Cell, Email, CreatedDateTime, ModifiedDateTime, Status)
            VALUES (@UserName, @Password, @Agent, @BrokerageFirm, @Address, @City, @State, @Zip, @Phone, @Cell, @Email, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 1)   

            SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_UserMaster_Mst WHERE pk_UserId=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('Username already exist !', -- Message text.
                       16, -- Severity.
                       1 -- State.
                       );
        END
end
Else
begin
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT pk_UserId FROM  dbo.tbl_UserMaster_Mst  WHERE UserName=@UserName and pk_UserId <> @UserID)
        BEGIN
            Update dbo.tbl_UserMaster_Mst set UserName=@UserName, Password=@Password, Agent=@Agent, BrokerageFirm=@BrokerageFirm,
            Address=@Address, City=@City, State=@State, Zip=@Zip, Phone=@Phone, Cell=@Cell, Email=@Email, ModifiedDateTime=GETDATE()
            Where pk_UserId=@UserID

            SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_UserMaster_Mst WHERE pk_UserId=@UserID
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('Username already exist !', -- Message text.
                       16, -- Severity.
                       1 -- State.
                       );
        END
end


END
```

Comment: What about your sp_RegisterUser procedure? As a side topic, you really should avoid using the sp_ prefix, or even better prefixes in general. The performance of sp_ is problem. There are also some other issues with this prefix. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: @SeanLange : Thanks for the suggestion but for the time being any way to fix this error please?

Comment: @SeanLange : I have updated the question with sp_RegisterUser procedure now please...you can have a look..!

Comment: Have you looked closely at the list of parameters you define in .net vs the parameters defined in the procedure. You are passing one extra parameter. You have this.txtAgentEmail.Value and txtDocusignEmail.Value in the list of values but there is only one email parameter in your procedure.

Comment: @SeanLange : Yes I modified the procedure and removed the comment marks from the procedure in order to include the remaining parameter as `@DocusignEmail` But still I am getting the same error..!

Comment: I can't debug it for you from here. You may need to run a sql trace and see what is being passed. The problem is that the parameter list between your code and your procedure are not the same. If you added the second email back in your procedure the lists would appear to be the same from what I see.

Comment: @SeanLange : I am missing SQL Profiler can you please run the trace for me.. Here are my SQL details : 
Server name : flax.arvixe.com  
Username : nicefellow1234   
Password : darkphp1234  
DB Name : CommercialSiteDB

Comment: Why in the world would you post connection credentials to your internet exposed database on a public forum???

Comment: you said you uncommented DocusignEmail....oddly it is still commented in your database procedure. I hope you have a backup since the user credentials you provided can do some unbelievably serious damage to your database.

Comment: @SeanLange : Not just it...I even tried to remove the DocusignEmail from the source code during passing the variables but still I was getting the same problem..Is there any exact way where can I really see that what values exactly get pass and exact error from where and which line I am getting cuz now it's just normally saying nothing more just this simple sentence..!

Comment: @SeanLange : Here I enabled tracing on the application..! Here check the values that are being passed : https://myunitedforms.com/Trace.axd?id=3

Comment: Did you ever actually change the procedure? Last I looked it was still commented. Not sure what that link you posted above is supposed to demonstrate because the page is empty. This problem boils down to basic debugging. Nobody can do this remotely.